# Variable substitution inside if statement

Tags: bash, shell, variables, substitution, quoting

I have the following bash script that I do not have control over:

```bash
set -x
echo "$CMD"
if ${CMD}; then
  echo "Success"
fi
```

I'm trying to run the following command: `bash -c "echo first && true"`. How do I pass it in for `CMD`, any ideas? Note here both echo and true are replacements for my actual more complex commands, here I replaced with these two trivial ones to highlight the issue in a simpler way.

I'd expect it to work with just:

```
❯ env CMD='bash -c "echo first && true"' bash magic.sh
+ echo 'bash -c "echo first && true"'
bash -c "echo first && true"
+ bash -c '"echo' first '&&' 'true"'
first: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

But it seems the variable substitution doesn't allow this, as the arguments get quoted.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code that you have no control over is fundamentally broken.  It cannot run arbitrary commands.  See [BashFAQ/050 (I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for more information.  Your best bet is to put your code in an executable file and put the path to the file in `CMD` or put the code in a function, export the function, and put the function name in `CMD`.

Comment: Sadly, the script and the run environment is not in my control; so neither of those will work. That being said I discovered just now that ` env CMD='eval echo first && true' bash magic.sh` works, at least for this simple example of mine.

Comment: After having sent the implementor of this script to some introductory course in bash scripting, just ask him to re-implement it properly. The question is a bit how to drive a car with broken engine without repairing the engine....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store all the commands in a shell script that exits with the appropriate code:

```
$ printf '#!/bin/bash\necho first && true\n' > /path/to/myscript
$ chmod +x /path/to/myscript
$ CMD=/path/to/myscript bash magic.sh
```

You can also declare a shell function:

```
bash -c '
    myscript(){
        echo first && true
    }
    CMD=myscript
    . magic.sh
'
```

Comment: Sadly, I do not have control over the runtime environment, so anything I do must be through the environment variable (is the only thing I control). For that reason, this solution will not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Revised using eval and second env-var
# Can another env-var be set as well?
Bash/001> cat test01.sh 
set -x
echo "$CMD"
if ${CMD}; then
  echo "Success"
fi
Bash/001> export BCMD='eval echo first && echo second && echo third && ls -l && true'
Bash/001> export CMD='bash -c $BCMD'
Bash/001> bash test01.sh 
+ echo 'bash -c $BCMD'
bash -c $BCMD
+ bash -c '$BCMD'
first
second
third
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 josep users 55 Dec 27 20:45 test01.sh
+ echo Success
Success
```

Comment: Ah, I've used echo purely for simplicity. I do not need to echo twice in practice, but more like I want to chain multiple commands together. So like ```env CMD='eval "bash -c \"echo yes && true""' bash magic.sh``` is perhaps a better example of what I would like to achieve. Hence, why important to use the echo via `bash`. So what I really want is to run ```echo yes && true``` that prints out only yes, and then runs the true command/builtin.

Comment: you don't need the indirect: `CMD='eval ...'` should work